# How to follow different paths depending on user choices in InnoSetup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to display several wizard pages using Inno Setup. But at some point, depending on the users task choice, I want to switch to another page, not necessarily the next page. Is it possible to "jump to another page" in Inno Setup pascal scripting. I couldn't find a related function.

As a last resort, I'm planning to use ShouldSkipPage() with a state variable.

Answer (score 1):

You must use **ShouldSkipPage**(). No other way exists.

But be attentive. From Inno-setup documentation:

> Note: This event function isn't called
>   for the wpWelcome, wpPreparing, and
>   wpInstalling pages, nor for pages that
>   Setup has already determined should be
>   skipped (for example,
>   wpSelectComponents in an install
>   containing no components).